# Change date in UILabel when click next and previous UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsdate, updates

Set a date in `UILabel`.
The click on "next" and "previous" buttons should change date inside this label.

I'm trying this code but next button click and show date next day date for e.g 01/05/2015 and previous button click and set date 29/05/2015 and next button click not display 02/05/2015

```
- (IBAction)changeToNextDay:(id)sender
{
    NSDateComponents* deltaComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [deltaComps setDay:+1];
    NSDate* tomorrow = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]  dateByAddingComponents:deltaComps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [myDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    NSString *stringFromDate = [myDateFormatter  stringFromDate:tomorrow];
    dateLabel.text = stringFromDate;
}

- (IBAction)changeToPreviousDay:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *datePlusOneDay = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(60 * 60 * 24)];
    NSLog(@"datePlusOneDay=%@",datePlusOneDay);

    NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [myDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    NSString *stringFromDate = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:datePlusOneDay];
    dateLabel.text = stringFromDate;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self Update_Date_By:0];
}

- (IBAction)changeToNextDay:(id)sender {
    [self Update_Date_By:1];
}

- (IBAction)changeToPreviousDay:(id)sender {
    [self Update_Date_By:-1];
}

-(void)Update_Date_By:(NSInteger)value {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateLabel.text];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
    dateComponents.day = value;
    if (value == 0) {
        date = [NSDate date];
    }
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:date options:0];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *finalDate_String = [dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate];
    dateLabel.text = finalDate_String;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this in a simple way.Follow the steps-

1. Declare two global variables for formatting and incrementing or decrementing the date.Such as-

   #import "ViewController.h"

   @interface ViewController ()
     {

   ```
   NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter;
   int day;
   ```

   }

   ```
   @end
   ```
2. In viewDidLoad,define the format of the date,set the current date in UILabel and initialize the day variable to 0-

   ```
   day=0;
   DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
   dateLabel.text=[DateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
   ```
3. For going to the next day Write the code in the body of the 'changeToNextDay' button-

   ```
   NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
   day+=1;
   NSDateComponents *components =[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
   [components setDay:day];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];  
    NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:now options:0];
    dateLabel.text=[DateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate];
   ```
4. For going to the previous day just copy the code from 'changeToNextDay' and paste it in 'changeToPreviousDay' button and change the line-

   ```
    day-=1 from day+=1;
   ```

Let me know if it works for you.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Function for Previous Day

```
-(void)previousDay
{
  NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];


    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    comps.day =-1;
    NSDate *previousDay = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    resultDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:previousDay];

}
```

function for next day

```
-(void)nextDay
{
  NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];


    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    comps.day =1;
    NSDate *nextDay = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    resultDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:nextDay];;

}
```

you can use this function